# jaudiotagger get mp3 frequency

Tags: java, id3v2, id3-tag, jaudiotagger

Anyone knows how to get mp3 Frequency (in Hz) using jaudiotagger library for Java? [jaudiotagger site](http://www.jthink.com/jaudiotagger/index.jsp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but this looks like it could help:

```
AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read(file);
String rate = f.getAudioHeader().getSampleRate();
```

There's also `getSampleRateAsNumber()` if you prefer an int.